# Binding Replicate Rows to a Dataframe

Tags: r

Can you improve on the following code?

```
A  <- B <- C  <-  c(-1,1) # for Factorial design
design  <- expand.grid(A=A, B=B,C=C) # for Factorial design
design  <- rbind(design, c(0,0,0),c(0,0,0),c(0,0,0))  #  centre points added to design
```

I want to do the last line with something more succinct.

When I tried the rbind(design, matrix(0,3,3)) the code crashed.  The col names for the matrix and design were different causing problems.  When I tried rbind(design, rep(c(0,0,0),3)) I only got one row appended rather than three.

Comment: `rbind(design, 0, 0, 0)`?

Comment: Brilliant thanks ... write it up as an answer with why it works and the points are yours ...

Comment: Np, feel free to write it down yourself. There is a duplicate somewhere anyway :)

Comment: @LyzandeR I did look for the a duplicate but I couldn't find one.

Answer (score 1):

This question was kindly answered by @LyzandeR above

```
rbind(design, 0, 0, 0)
```

Which works by recycling each of the values for each of the rows.

Hence,

```
A  <- B <- C  <-  c(-1,1) # for Factorial design
design  <- expand.grid(A=A, B=B,C=C) # for Factorial design
design  <- rbind(design,0,0,0)  #  centre points added to design
```